# run failed on simple c++ programme

Tags: c++

I am doing c++, i learnt it in a module at uni, and just revisiting it for some practice. I keep getting "run failed exit value 1" when i run my program (see below). Any ideas why? (probably something obvious).

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int n = 30; 
  for (int i = 0; i < (n + 1); i++) {
    if ( n % i == 0) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `<cstdlib>` and `<vector>` here, do you? Does this compile, BTW?

Comment: when in doubt, add more cout statements. starting with hello world is not a crime.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing a *modulo by zero* in

```
if (n % i == 0)
```

when `i = 0`, hence the error.

Comment: action speaks louder than words. i.e. mark the answer.